# Typescript: Why doesn't Material-UI "withStyles()" work with an explicit constructor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Edit:

Note that the incorrect constructor was generated by IntelliJ IDEA. This has now been fixed, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35178

---

I am looking at using Material-UI in my app, but I'm having some trouble with the `withStyles` styling solution in combination with TypeScript.

I'm trying to make my own little wrapper component, based off the [Popper documentation](https://material-ui.com/utils/popper/).

The problem is, if I define a constructor explicitly the way I'm used to (`(B)` in the code below), then this line:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(HelpComponent);
```

Give this error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/ts/screen/keyword/HelpComponent.tsx:150:35 
    TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof HelpComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'.
  Type 'typeof HelpComponent' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<never>'.
    Type 'typeof HelpComponent' provides no match for the signature '(props: never, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

The only way I've been able to make this work is to omit the explicit constructor and define state as a field (`(A)` in the code below).

Is there a way to declare a constructor the normal way when I use `withStyles`?

I actually don't mind setting the state directly like this, it's a bit less boilerplate.  Am I giving up anything by initialising the state outside the constructor this way?

Ultimately, I just don't understand that TypeScript error message - can anyone explain what it's trying to say?

```
import {
  createStyles,
  Paper,
  Popper,
  Theme,
  WithStyles,
  withStyles
} from '@material-ui/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import {ReactNode, SyntheticEvent} from 'react';
import {EventUtil} from "appUtil/EventUtil";
import {WarningSvg} from "component/svg-icon/WarningSvg";
let log = require("log4javascript").getLogger("HelpComponent");

export interface HelpComponentProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  children:ReactNode;
}

export interface HelpComponentState {
  open:boolean;
  arrowRef?: HTMLElement;
}

class HelpComponent extends React.Component<HelpComponentProps, HelpComponentState> {
  helpRef!: HTMLElement;

  // (A)
  state = {open: false, arrowRef: undefined};

  // (B)
  // constructor(props: HelpComponentProps, context: HelpComponentState){
  //   super(props, context);
  //   this.state = {open: false, arrowRef: undefined};
  // }

  handleClick = (event:SyntheticEvent<any>) => {
    EventUtil.stopClick(event);
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open,});
  };

  handleArrowRef = (node:HTMLElement) => {
    this.setState({
      arrowRef: node,
    });
  };

  render(){
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return <span ref={(ref)=>{if(ref) this.helpRef = ref}}>
      <WarningSvg onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      <Popper id={"help-popper"} className={classes.popper} transition
        open={this.state.open} anchorEl={this.helpRef}
        modifiers={{arrow:{enabled:true, element: this.state.arrowRef}}}
      >
        <span className={classes.arrow} ref={this.handleArrowRef}/>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>{this.props.children}</Paper>
      </Popper>
    </span>;
  }

}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    height: 400,
    overflow: 'auto',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
  scroll: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '230%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    height: '230%',
  },
  legend: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  paper: {
    maxWidth: 400,
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  select: {
    width: 200,
  },
  popper: {
    zIndex: 1,
    '&[x-placement*="bottom"] $arrow': {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      marginTop: '-0.9em',
      width: '3em',
      height: '1em',
      '&::before': {
        borderWidth: '0 1em 1em 1em',
        borderColor: `transparent transparent ${theme.palette.common.white} transparent`,
      },
    },
    '&[x-placement*="top"] $arrow': {
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      marginBottom: '-0.9em',
      width: '3em',
      height: '1em',
      '&::before': {
        borderWidth: '1em 1em 0 1em',
        borderColor: `${theme.palette.common.white} transparent transparent transparent`,
      },
    },
    '&[x-placement*="right"] $arrow': {
      left: 0,
      marginLeft: '-0.9em',
      height: '3em',
      width: '1em',
      '&::before': {
        borderWidth: '1em 1em 1em 0',
        borderColor: `transparent ${theme.palette.common.white} transparent transparent`,
      },
    },
    '&[x-placement*="left"] $arrow': {
      right: 0,
      marginRight: '-0.9em',
      height: '3em',
      width: '1em',
      '&::before': {
        borderWidth: '1em 0 1em 1em',
        borderColor: `transparent transparent transparent ${theme.palette.common.white}`,
      },
    },
  },
  arrow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    fontSize: 7,
    width: '3em',
    height: '3em',
    '&::before': {
      content: '""',
      margin: 'auto',
      display: 'block',
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      borderStyle: 'solid',
    },
  },
});

export default withStyles(styles)(HelpComponent);
```

Versions:

- "typescript": "3.0.3"
- "@types/react": "16.4.14"
- "@types/react-dom": "16.0.7"
- "@material-ui/core": "3.1.1"
- "webpack": "4.19.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `React.ComponentType`:

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | StatelessComponent<P>;
```

The alternative you are trying to use is `ComponentClass`, which is defined as:

```
interface ComponentClass<P = {}, S = ComponentState> extends StaticLifecycle<P, S> {
    new (props: P, context?: any): Component<P, S>;
    // ...
}
```

Notice that the `context` parameter is optional (`?` mark).  The problem is that the `context` parameter of your constructor is not optional, so `HelpComponent` is not compatible with callers that expect to be able to omit the `context` argument.  If you make the parameter optional, the error should go away.

When TypeScript reports the error that `typeof HelpComponent` is not assignable to the union type `React.ComponentType`, it semi-arbitrarily picks one member of the union type to report a detailed error.  Unfortunately, it didn't pick the one you intended, so the error message isn't very useful.

> I actually don't mind setting the state directly like this, it's a bit less boilerplate. Am I giving up anything by initialising the state outside the constructor this way?

Yes, by overriding the `state` property, you may be unintentionally changing its type to be something different from the state type argument that you passed to the `React.Component` base class.

Comment: Ohhhhh, snap.  Thankyou for the quick answer.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to make the context as optional.